# How to redirect user to html error page instead of the exception thrown via ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Here is the ampscript code.  If I change the column name to be Email Address 2 for instance, the code never gets to redirecting to the HTML Error page.  It immediately throws code exception on the screen.

```
SET @status = UpsertData("ENT.ABC_OPTOUT", 3, "EMAIL ADDRESS", @e, "Legal Entity", @attribute, "Record Type", "C", "Collected Date", FORMAT(SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "TIMESTAMP", SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()), "Source", "EXACT", "First Name", @fn, "Last Name", @ln, "Hashed Email Address", @subkey)

IF @status == 0 THEN

  Redirect(@error_url)  

ENDIF

An unexpected error has occurred!
Error Message:  The Data Extension field name for a UpsertData function call is invalid. A field of this name does not exist. Function Call: UpsertData("ENT.ABC_OPTOUT", 3, "EMAIL ADDRESS", @e, "Legal Entity", @attribute, "Record Type", "C", "Collected Date", FORMAT(SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "TIMESTAMP", SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()), "Source", "EXACT", "First Name", @fn, "Last Name", @ln, "Hashed Email Address", @subkey) Data Extension Name: CASL_INS_CONSENT_OPTOUT Field Name: EMAIL ADDRESS Parameter Name: ColumnName Parameter Ordinal: 3

Description:    An unexpected error occurred during the execution of the page.

line 0, column 0
Exception Info:
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is a "mix" of server side javascript and ampscript.  Then, use the server side JS to do a try catch.  It looks something like this.

Before your UPSERT, close the AMPscript with ]%%.

Then,  add (I don't know how to escape the script block):

```
 <script runat="server" language="javascript">
 Platform.Load("Core","1");  //Required to load SSJS library
 try
 {
 </script>
 %%[  SET @somevar = UpsertData  ... ]%%
 <script runat="server" language="javascript">
 } catch(err) { 
 </script>
 %%[Redirect(@error_url) ]%%
 <script runat="server" language="javascript">
 } 
 </script>
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Great answer, but just wondering why you write `\LESSTHAN script GREATER THAN` instead of just `</script>`?

Comment: For what ever reason, yesterday when I did this, the script tags were getting interpreted and not displaying, and I couldn't figure out why.  Today it works, so I made the fixes.

Comment: I tried this as follows however it worked once but after that it is still throwing code exception:

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as follows however it worked once but after that it is still throwing code exception:

```
less than script runat="server" language="javascript" greater than

 Platform.Load("Core","1");  //Required to load SSJS library
 try
 {
     less than /script greater than

     %%[        
          SET @status = UpsertData("ENT.CASL_INS_CONSENT_OPTOUT", 3, "EMAIL ADDRESS", @e, "Legal Entity", @attribute, "Record Type", "C", "Collected Date", FORMAT(SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "TIMESTAMP", SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()), "Source", "EXACT", "First Name", @fn, "Last Name", @ln, "Hashed Email Address", @subkey)
     ]%%
     less than script runat="server" language="javascript" greater than
 } catch(err) { 
     less than /script greater than
    %%[     
        IF @TestMode != true THEN
              IF @status != 1 THEN
                  Redirect(@error_url)  
             ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ]%%

    less than script runat="server" language="javascript" greater than
 } 
less than /script greater than
```

Comment: When you say "it worked once"... one time EVER or one time / page load?  Also, it the error the same?

Comment: worked one time ever.  yes error is same.

Comment: More info:  It seems to work on the enterprise account and not the child business accounts.

Comment: That is a very informative comment!  Your data extension needs to live in the Shared DataExtension folder in order for it to be shared across BU's.  Can you verify that to be the case?  If its not, go to the DE listing in the application, select CASL_INS_CONSENT_OPTOUT and click move.

Comment: Yes this is a shared data extension in the shared data extension folder.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ENT. prefix?  We may be grasping at straws, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Please update the question with this information, as this is not an answer.