# Redirect to error page via SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am trying to error Handle my Cloud page in SFMC.

If anything goes wrong in the Ampscript Block, user should be redirected to an error page. There is a success scenario where I redirect the user to Success page within Ampscript.

I have tried using a mix of SSJS and AmpScript. Here is a Sample code. Is there a way of doing a redirect through SSJS directly instead of using a mix of SSJS and AMPScript

Issue with this code is if I comment out the Success Redirection, it works. If I put both redirects, it goes to the catch block every time

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
 Platform.Load("core", "1.1.3");
try{
</script>
%%[
/*Do Operations Search Operations on DE.

set @confirmation = Success_URL
Redirect(@Confirmation)

]%% <script runat="server" language="javascript">
 } catch(e) { 
  </script>
 %%[
 set @errorUrl= /*Some URL*/
 Redirect(@errorUrl)

 ]%%
 <script runat="server" language="javascript">
 } 
 </script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading core 1.1.3?  As far as I know, 1.1.1 is the current release.

Comment: Have you spat out anything on the page before the redirect? You can't start writing to the buffer and then redirect. So any HTML/Writes/outputs before the code above might be your issue.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38813/how-to-redirect-user-to-html-error-page-instead-of-the-exception-thrown-via-amps), this might help you.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Actually, 1.1.5 is the latest library.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation that mentioned anything past 1.1.1

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, I guess Platform Version is not an issue.

Comment: @AndrewMcLeod, No there is nothing that I am printing on this page. Above is the full code snippet. Just doing some Ampscript manipulations and storage on some variables.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra, That is what I am trying to do here. Still no luck

Comment: @AnkitBajpai why don't you use the redirect SSJS function? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesRedirect.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem related to your code but a [known SFMC issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqnFQAS). Unfortunately, it won't be fixed.

You need to either do a redirect outside of a try block or leverage a workaround [shared by @Gortonington on StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/311934/91679).

Answer (score 1):

According to the SSJS documentation, there is a **[Redirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesRedirect.htm)** function available within the core SSJS library.

Here is the example below:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

try {
    //DO SOMETHING and REDIRECT
    Redirect("http://success-page.com",true);
 } 
 catch(e) {
    //REDIRECT TO ERROR PAGE
    Redirect("http://error-page.com",true);
} 
 </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a known issue, this solution will not work. Every redirect (be it AMPScript or SSJS) will error out within the try block in SFMC: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqnFQAS