# SSJS redirecting to wrong page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I have a processing cloud page and the page redirects correctly to success page but when I add in extra bit of code for error page redirect, records evaluating success still goes to the error page. Am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance.

```
try {
   var token = getToken(setup);
   var success = false
   if (!!token) success = triggerEvent(token setup, data);
   if (!!success) {
      Redirect("https://successpage.com", true);}
   else {
      Redirect("https://errorpage.com", true);}
} catch (e) {
  Redirect("https://errorpage.com",true);
 }
}
```

Comment: What are your getToken() and triggerEvent() returning? Could they be returning undefined or raising an error leading you to always ending up at the error page?

Comment: If I remove the error page redirect, and replace with write, it works fine. When it is success, it will redirect to success page and error is displayed on the page. Problem is only when I add the 2 error page redirects.

Comment: Can you try flipping the second param of your Redirects from "true" to "false" and clear your cache/bypass the cache in developer tools? You're setting a permanent redirection (301) that would be cached by your browser.

Comment: hey @Macca, doesn't seem to work. Still sends to error page. :(

Comment: To help debugging, make sure you don't just redirect to "https://errorpage.com" both times, but instead use "https://errorpage.com?test=1"  and https://errorpage.com?test=2" so you know which condition fired. Helps isolate what is going on.

Comment: Redirect function inside try throws an error - reffer to this respons by Gortonington - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311799/ssjs-platform-response-redirect-throws-unknown-error-error-in-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue around that all redirect functions will throw an exception due to the 'breaking' from the script.  There are a couple ways to get around this, please see this [**SFSE post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311799/ssjs-platform-response-redirect-throws-unknown-error-error-in-application?noredirect=1&lq=1) that recently experienced the same issue or check out a [**post**](https://www.howtosfmc.com/posts/the-catches-of-try-catch-in-sfmc-ssjs/) I made on **[HowToSFMC.com](https://www.howtosfmc.com)** about this as well as other potential pitfalls with Try/Catch.

**Basic synopsis of the issue:**

> It appears this is a well documented .Net issue revolving around that Redirects will throw a ‘ThreadAbort’ exception, which would trigger the catch block to run instead. Now SFMC SSJS does not have all the great exception handling capabilities that you can see in languages like .Net.

**and my recommended solution:**

```js
<script runat="server">
    var redirect = 'https://google.com'

    try{
          Platform.Response.Redirect(redirect)
    } catch(e) {
        var desc = e.description; //Pulls the description from error object
        if(desc.indexOf("ExactTarget.OMM.AMPScriptRedirectException") > -1) {
          Platform.Response.Write(desc) //This is arbitrary as will not be run
        } else {
          redirect = 'https://yahoo.com'
          Platform.Response.Redirect(redirect)
        }
    }
</script>
```

By throwing the redirect into an if statement, you remove it from being processed if the exception thrown is just from the redirect, it will instead only be processed for other exceptions.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!