# Redirect a cloud page to an external URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl, sfmcadmin

I have a cloudpage that has been replaced by a similar landing page on my website. How do i set up a redirect on the cloudpage so that everyone who lands on the cloudpage is automatically redirected to my website?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_utilitiesRedirect.html

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to add this AMPscript at the beginning of the cloud page

```
%%[
set @link = 'http://www.google.com'
Redirect(@link)
]%%
```

Alternatively, you can use SSJS as well but the logic is a bit strange. It will run the catch redirect in the following script.
(Described here: [SSJS Platform.Response.Redirect() throws unknown error: Error in Application](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311799/ssjs-platform-response-redirect-throws-unknown-error-error-in-application?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
<script runat="server">
try{
    Platform.Response.Redirect('http://www.google.com');
} catch(e) {
    Platform.Response.Redirect('http://www.google.com');
}
</script>
```